# QAF | How to pass ArrayList or Map from one step to another step

Tags: bdd, qaf

In QAF (Gerkin), I want to pass map data or Array List from one step to another.
I have tried following:

Step 1 (inside Step Def):

```
    List<Object> tdData = new ArrayList<>(data.values());
    store(tdData, "data_values");
```

Step 2 (inside Step Def):

```
   System.out.println(getBundle().getObject("data_values")); // Printing the list

   ArrayList<Object> tmpValues = getBundle().getObject("data_values"); // Throwing error
   System.out.println(tmpValues.get(0));
```

Able to print the list as string with "System.out.println(getBundle().getObject("data_values"));" but not able to assign the list to ArrayList. Throwing below error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project qaf-blank-project-maven: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/XXXXXXX/Downloads/60b76ff32243f233355d048b/src/test/java/com/sample/steps/steps.java:[125,57] incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast object to list.

```
   List<Object> tmpValues = (List<Object>)getBundle().getObject("data_values"); 

   System.out.println(tmpValues.get(0));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Array list is working. Any help, how can I pass Map between steps?

Comment: you can use map same way as list. For example ,if `data` is of type `Map<Object,Object>` object  then  `store(data, "testDataFromMyStep");` to retrieve    `Map<Object,Object> testdata = (Map<Object,Object> )getBundle().getObject("testDataFromMyStep"); `